# Reasons for using the same word for people and language of a country?

Tags: meaning, language-evolution

Ever since my first days of learning English I have been puzzled by this simple phenomenon:

Why the word "English" can both mean the English language, and the English people?

Is there any historical reason for this?  By "historical", I mean, is the usage already like this a long time ago?

I am asking this because "people" and "language" are two related but very different concepts.  Why use the same word for two different things?  (Well, of course a single word can have two or more completely different and unrelated meanings, but that's not what I am asking here.)

I am a Chinese.  In Chinese the words for people of a country and the language of that country are different.  For example, for English people, we would just say "English people", and for the language, we would say "English language".  I don't know what is the case in other languages.

Comment: The same is true for French, German, Spanish, and, as you so aptly demonstrated, Chinese. The Chinese people speak Chinese. In Japan, 日本人 speak　日本語. Such languages require an explicit declaration of subject. English does not. The subject is understood from context. "Do you speak French?" "The French like red wine with meals."

Comment: Words like *English* but also *Latin* and most other names of languages refer historically primarily to the people or their land; so Latin means "of Latium", the region in Italy; and English means "of the Angles", the Germanic tribe. The name of the language they speak is based on that. I believe it was historically rather "the English language" and "lingua Latina": leaving out the word "language/lingua" is technically or etymologically ellipsis, I believe. And this occurred/occurs in most European languages. So that's why it is the way it is now.

Comment: Note that while we generally use the same **adjectives** to refer to languages and people, we don't generally use the same **nouns.** The language of the English people is _English,_ but the people are _Englishmen._ (There are exceptions, like Germans, Greeks, and Italians.)

Comment: @Cerberus You should post that as an answer. That's a much better explanation than mine.

Comment: You're confusing [synonymy and polysemy](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104054/what-is-the-average-number-of-meanings-for-a-word-in-english/104060#104060) here, when you say 'Well, of course a single word can have two or more completely different and unrelated meanings'. This is not true - they will be two different words spelt and pronounced the same way (like bear, the creature and bear = carry). They will be listed under two headwords in a dictionary. On the other hand, 'English' (the people) and 'English' (the language) are two senses of the same word.

Comment: @adj7388: That's very kind, but I'll leave it to you guys!

Comment: Actually, if you are using nouns *English* is the language; the people are  *the English*.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the word English is a noun when referring to the language, and an adjective when referring to the people.

Comment: @Robusto, it's funny that you should say that languages like Japanese require the _subject_ (not the right word, though right now I can't think of a better one either), when Japanese is (as I'm sure you know) notoriously liberal with dropping (grammatical) subjects whenever it feels like it! :-)

Comment: @BraddSzonye, I wouldn't say that—Englishmen is not the term used for the people of England, but for individuals from England. The people as a whole (which is what usually has the same name as the demonymic adjectives) is simply _the English_.

Comment: @FJDU, not exactly like that. If ‘English’ is a _noun_, it can refer to either the people (“The English have the worst dental hygiene in Europe”) or the language (“English is tough stuff!”); there's usually a definite article before it when it's the people. When it's an _adjective_, it can refer to absolutely anything because an adjective needs to modify something: “The English _language/parliament/Patient_”, “_Ge_ is English”, etc. It doesn't refer specifically to people or language, but it _can_ refer to both, if they happen to be the nouns it is modifying.

Comment: @Janus: I phrased that poorly, sorry. What I meant was that they don't use adjectives to stand in for nouns in the case of language the way we do. But you're right. I would go even further, and state that whenever possible the Japanese drop elements of syntax, especially subjects ( and more especially pronouns), and rely on politeness markers and the like to indicate who or what is being discussed.

Answer (score 4):

(Note: I actually wanted to post this as a comment, not an answer, but for some reason it doesn't seem to do anything when I try—simply does not react.)

FJDU, you are missing the fact that in Chinese, you do not really say *English language/people*, since Chinese does not have a way of morphologically deriving adjectives from nouns. What you really say is *England language* and *England people*. Different languages derive words from each other in different ways; in English, an adjective can be derived from country (and similar) names, and these adjectives can then, like so many other, be used as nouns. If you simply make a noun out of an adjective that means ‘of England’, it makes sense that that will most often refer to either the people of England or the language of England.

There are languages where simple adjectives, nouns for people, and nouns for languages have three different forms (Irish and Scottish Gaelic work like this, and I have some vague memory of reading somewhere that Turkish does too?); there are languages where two are the same and one is different (English is partly one of these, at least for some languages/countries; Germanic languages in general share the same distribution of adjective + language being the same and people being a different word; Finnish has a slightly different model where adjective + people are the same word, but language is simply the name of the country/place itself, underived); and there are languages where all three are the same (such as Chinese).

There is no real ‘reason’ as such for all this. It is just part of what makes languages different from each other.

Comment: I know how you feel, it can be really frustrating when you can't post an answer as a comment. +1

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't understand why you say that in Chinese all three are the same. For the adjective, we may say "英国的" (of England, or of UK), for the people, we say "英国人" (=England people or UK people, as you said), and for English language the word is "英语", which may be seen as an abbreviation of "英国的语言" (=the language of England).  BTW, the word "英国" always refers to UK (=联合王国), though "英" is obviously a phonetic translation of "En" in England (while 英格兰=England).

Comment: Note that I said _morphologically_. Chinese does not possess morphology (unless you count tone sandhi and 儿化), so basically there is no way to make different forms. Instead, you simply use the name of the country as an attributive noun, with or without the specific attribution marker 的. This does not make a new, unique _word_ as such, but simply creates a compound.

Comment: The UK is not a good example because it's abbreviated in different ways; but take Sweden/Swede/Swedish as an example: 瑞典/瑞典人/瑞典语. You could also say 瑞典狗 or 瑞典航空公司 (except there isn't one), the construction would be exactly the same—no special adjectival or demonymic form, just country name + (optionally 的) + head noun.

Comment: @Janus Thanks. I don't know much about these "academic" issues. I don't see much difference between changing England into "English" or into "England-ish" (maybe the first requires the Backspace key why the second does not?). Namely, you don't consider changing "英国" into "英国的" as a morphological change, while I can't see the importance of this. Chinese do have a word "英式", which means, well, the adjective English (not for people)，and a word "英制"，which means Imperial (referring to things like "inch").

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ultimately I guess all the adjectives in any language have a corresponding noun. Different languages make this correspondence differently, whether by changing the noun (in English), or by adding something to the noun, and the added part might be omitted sometimes (in Chinese). But "adding" is also "changing", right? That's why I don't see big difference whether it is morphologically changing a word or not. Sorry for my ignorance of these linguistic issues.

Comment: Not all adjectives have corresponding nouns—‘my’, for example, does not. There is also a difference between adding something that is a word or particle in its own right (basically making a compound word of sorts) and changing the basic makeup of a word. The latter is an unpredictable process that you need to know by rote; the former is a simple process of tacking something on, like building blocks. If you want to know how to use 好 as an adverb (of degree), for example, you simply do what you always do: 得 + 好. To do the same with ‘good’, you need to know to use ‘well’, an unrelated word.

Answer (score 1):

It's often frustrating to ask 'why is it this way' in any language. The most common answer is 'it's that way just because that's the way it is' :)

In English, though, part of the answer to your question is that we can tell from context whether you're referring to an English person or the English language.

For example, if I say 'He is English', you would know that I'm not talking about the language because a person cannot be a language.

Likewise, if I say 'She speaks English', you would know that I'm not talking about an English person, because a person cannot be spoken.

So context is the key. That's how we know the difference. As to 'why', well, that's just the way it is :)

By the way, in French the same phenomenon occurs: a 'French person' is a 'français', and the language is also 'français'. Also in French, an English person is an 'anglais', and the language is also 'anglais'. I suspect it is like this in many other Romantic languages. And you can tell the difference from context.